# Url is not showing any information

Tags: php, html

I am developing a web application that should be open to all attacks of owasp list. Most of the attacks are using url to get information but in my web application nothing is showed in url except name of file. Although i have set session variable. Anyone knows how can I show these values in url?

Comment: This is really impressive. You have issues making an application attackable due to lack of knowledge of the technology you want to test. Doesn't that give you a small hint where to start learning?

Answer (score 0):

You can see variables in URL only when you use a **GET** protocol:
Your url will be :

```
site.com/file.php?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Else, you can use **POST** protocol, and your url will be

```
site.com/file.php
```

It's **not a secure way** to send datas, but it just hide them.
It's more simple to change a variable with GET than POST, but you can change/add every variables with POST protocol too.

Comment: Actually you can use GET variables in POST requests too with most implementations...